# compile time error in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Am running asp.net application.I try to build sample site using gridview.I got compilation error as below,

```
CS1061: 'ASP.gridedit_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_RowUpdated' and no extension method 'GridView1_RowUpdated' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.gridedit_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Line 13:         <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" 
Line 14:               AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
Line 15:               DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `GridView1_RowUpdated` event handler declared in your page markup, but your code behind does not contain such a function.

Comment: hi frederick, thank u so much this works out..i got another exception now as Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.

Comment: @jeni, we'll need more information to understand that error. Can you post the relevant parts of your code and the full exception backtrace (possibly in another question)?

Comment: hi fredrick thanks for ur reply..i solved the problem..i done some basic mistakes in my database.anyway i got some aspect of errors i wil post in the next que..